# Updating .gitconfig resulted in two files

Tags: git, git-config

**SOLVED:** *See the comment section for the answer*

Image illustrating my problem:

[image: .gitconfig files]

So I was troubleshooting a Visual Studio error which implied adding information to my gitconfig file. I right-clicked on the file, decided to open with Notepad (so that I could edit the file), and then did my editing. However, upon updating the file, my computer proceeded to generate a new gitconfig file, so now I have two (?).

The weird thing is that the unnamed gitconfig file, which was named `.gitconfig` prior to editing, is now unnamed (?). And the file at the bottom which is now named `.gitconfig` contains the information, that I updated the original file (which is, the file above) with.

Has this occured to anyone before? I would assume, that I somehow don't have permission to update the original `.gitconfig`, so instead of me updating it it just creates a new? Also, does anyone know how to handle this, in terms of which one to delete?

Comment: Do you have "Show file extensions" turned on in Windows Explorer?  I would put money on "no", and that the second file is actually named `.gitconfig.gitconfig` because of the way Notepad handles file extensions.  (You have to make sure to set extension to "all files" when saving.)

Comment: @0x5453 I just realized that instead of overwriting my old file (which didn't have a name, but was just a GITCONFIG-File), I saved it as a completely new file called `.gitconfig`. Thank you for the help.